# Linux: Reading the output of readlink /proc/pid/exe within a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, procfs

So I am writing a bash script which will run through all of the process ids in /proc/[pid] and read the executable that was used to run it.

From what I have had a looked at, the /proc filesystem contains the /proc/[pid]/exe symbolic link. Within the bash script I am trying work out how to read the value of "readlink /proc/[pid]/exe" to check if (deleted) or nothing is returned to find out whether the original executable exists on the disk or not.

Is there a way of doing this, so far I have?

```
#!/bin/bash
pid = "0"

while [ $pid -lt 32769 ]
do
    if [-d /proc/$pid]; then
        if [-f /proc/$pid/exe]; then
            echo $pid
            readlink /proc/$pid/exe
        fi
    fi
    pid = $[$pid+1]
done
```

This fails to work and always returns nothing.I am trying to list all of the processes that no longer have their executables available on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls /proc | awk '/^[[:digit:]]+/{print $1}'); do
  if [ -h /proc/$i/exe ]; then
    echo -n "$i: "
    if readlink /proc/$i/exe >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
      echo "executable exists"
    else
      echo "executable not found"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Why not `for i in /proc/[0-9]*/exe; do` ?

Comment: This worked for me, except for the for loop. I finally went with the while loop. 'while [ $pid -lt 32769 ]'. Although this method does not work for deleted executables.

Comment: Good one, @caf!  Just didn't think of that method.

@DesiBoyz, out of curiosity, what was wrong with the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your script to make it work. Notice that -f checks whether a file name represents a **regular** file. I would return false for a symbolic link:

```
pid="0"
while [ $pid -lt 32769 ]
do
    if [ -d /proc/$pid ]; then
        if [ -h /proc/$pid/exe ]; then
            echo $pid
            readlink /proc/$pid/exe
        fi
    fi
    pid=$[$pid+1]
done
```

Comment: Thanks, OrenD but that doesn't seem to work. I have added more detail above.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version of your script that should work for you.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a reference for such things such as -h, -f, -d etc? I tried searching couldn't find any references.

Comment: Check the manpage for the 'test' command to get info on those flags.

Answer (score 0):

you can read returned value after any command in shell by printing $? variable:

```
 readlink
 echo $?
```

if link is invalid, $? will be bigger than 0.

however if link exist and actual file is deleted, you can use something like:

```
ls `readlink somelink`
```

Comment: my bad, I got the wrong idea, I modified the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
   readlink -f `ls --dereference /proc/$pid/exe`
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.